# How to make this homemade enable? Need the OUT voltage to become -6 V when the enable voltage is turned on to 3.3 V

Tags: mosfet, negative

[image: What I'm trying to make in LTSpice]

I don't need to be using a MOSFET, just figured that would be the way to go.

Comment: you could use a relay

Comment: Do you already have a -6V supply available in your real design, or are you asking how to make one?

Comment: Why do you need to control -6V and what power max?

Comment: @jsotola, surely a relay would typically be bulky, expensive and high-current compared to solid state circuit solutions, so a poor choice.

Comment: @rdtsc I already have the -6V available.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I am designing a power sequencer, so I want this -6V to turn on after another voltage is turned on

Comment: Without threshold specs on sequencing and tolerances, my design is perfect since it meets spec (Series pass -6V with 3V but if you need tight threshold specs say so)

Answer (score 0):

That will never work.

This is one option using a 5.6V Zener.

[image]

Notice the orientation of battery polarity and input shifts level down to the gate, rather than your incorrect control on the drain.

You ought to get familiar with solutions already posted on switches, FETs Vgs(th) logic level thresholds and RdsOn.

**Any switches ideally should have a spec for input voltage, current and output voltage current min/max. and load or product with link**